# PopupMenuButton how to remove grey hightlight text-layer

Tags: flutter, popupmenu

There is PopupMenuButton with submenu. Fullcode:

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
              tooltip: 'Меню задачи',
              onSelected: (value) {
                changeTaskStatus(value, context, data, ref);
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<int>>[
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: PopupMenuButton(
                    tooltip: "Изменить статус",
                    onSelected: (value) {
                      changeTaskStatus(value, context, data, ref);
                    },
                    child: const Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Изменить статус',
                          style: TextStyle(height: 3),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                      ],
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        <PopupMenuEntry<int>>[
                      const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                        value: 0,
                        child: Text('В работе'),
                      ),
                      const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                        value: 1,
                        child: Text('Выполнена'),
                      ),
                      const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                        value: 2,
                        child: Text('Отменена'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const PopupMenuDivider(),
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                  value: 4,
                  child: Text('Редактировать задачу'),
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                  value: 3,
                  child: Text('Удалить'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

And in final I have a extra grey highlighted on hover text-layer:

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

How to remove this extra highlight on Text-widget inside Child of PopupMenuButton?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `highlightColor` and `hoverColor`

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,//if you want remove splash color
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: PopupMenuButton<int>(
```

Comment: This option does not work correctly. In this case, all child elements of PopupMenuButton<int> stop highlighting on hover.

Comment: if you are trying to remove from just item, I am not  sure of that

Comment: not working too